# Is this a $\log,\zeta$ relationship

Tags: logarithms, special-functions

Is there a relationship between $\zeta(x^{1/x})$ and $x/\log(x)?$ They seem remarkably close in value.

Comment: For large $x$? $$x^{1/x} = \exp \left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right) = 1 + \frac{\log x}{x} + O\left(\frac{\log^2 x}{x^2}\right).$$

Comment: and for real $s > 0,$ $$  \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \gamma + (s-1) h(s-1), $$ where $h$ is real analytic